# Who created the service in bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is there a way to see who was creating a app or a service in Bluemix where I have multiple users/developers in a org/space ?

Espen

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Bluemix CLI](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/bx_cli.html#bluemix_cli) you can find out about the events associated with an application by using the command:

`bx app events <application_name>`

There is not a similar command for services.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the `Overview` of an application, in the `Activity Feed` you can see a username associated with every Start, stop, and update of the app.